# Unable to get the content of a set when scraping is finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a script to parse all the links recursively until there is no more from the left sided window under `Any Department` from [this webpage](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=zg_bs_nav_0). As the selectors throughout all the depth are identical, the following script can parse them flawlessly.

What I wish to do now is print the content of `item_links()` which contains unique links when the execution is done. However, I can't make it and this is where I'm stuck at this moment. To be clearer, I wish to print the unique links when the execution is finished.

Getting all links including duplicates:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=zg_bs_nav_0'

def get_links(s,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    link_list = []
    for item in soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"):
        item_link = item.get("href")
        link_list.append(item_link)
        yield item_link

    for new_link in link_list:
        yield from get_links(s,new_link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'
        for elem in get_links(s,link):
            print(elem)
```

Can't find a way to print the content of `item_links`:

```
def get_links(s,link,item_links=set()):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    link_list = []
    for item in soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"):
        item_link = item.get("href")
        link_list.append(item_link)
        item_links.append(item_link)  #trying to include the links into a set
        yield item_link #it prints the urls being parsed though not necessary

    for new_link in link_list:
        yield from get_links(s,new_link,item_links)
```

How can I print the content of `item_links`?

Comment: you should use `return  item_links` to send it back from `get_links`. Eventually you should run it with external `set()` as paramater - `unique = set()` and `get_links(s,link, unique)` - and then you should have all in `unique`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create external `set()` and send it as argument - and later you can print it.

```
def get_links(item_links):
    item_links.add('link1')
    item_links.add('link2')
    item_links.add('link1')  # again the same
    
unique_links = set()

get_links(unique_links)

print(unique_links)
```

---

BTW: `set()` needs `add()` instead of `append()`

Comment: Thanks for the idea @furas. Ain't [this](https://pastebin.com/SqSpeeHb) doing the same thing as well? I'll confirm it once I'm done testing. Btw, using `append` instead of `add` was a stupid typo. Thanks.

Comment: in your version you doesn't create external `set()` and you don't send it as argument but you create local `set()` - `get_links(..., item_links=set())` so later you can't get it outside function. You would have to use `return item_links` to send it outside function - but it makes problem because you already use `yield` to send other values.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I'll rectify that accordingly when in need. However, the current implementation that I've linked to is what I was after.